# Google Apps Script: Find Cells With a Certain Value, Then Set the Background Color of It

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am familiar with JavaScript, but I am new to Google Apps Script.

My goal is to search through the whole sheet, find all the "foo"s and change the cell background color to red, then find all the "bar"s and change the cell background color to blue. To see an example, this a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11gWRIXxCdSuhNthZ5dcmc6Maj5g2cR-jhGOsrWjdpaI/edit?usp=sharing).

I would rather put a picture, but I cannot.

I was stuck on this problem for a long time. Any help would mean a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Incude code: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302091/2213940. Write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Zig Thanks for the information. I don't use Stack Overflow a lot, so I'm sorry if my questions aren't the most experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speadsheets have a very nice conditional formatting built in.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en